# execution flow after while loop java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i=0;
     int arr[] = new int[10];
     while(scan.hasNext()){
         arr[i++] = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println("sud");
     }
     System.out.println("hello");
}

}
```

If the input is `1 2 3 4 5` then it print 5 times. sud means while loop is working  but it does not go to the `System.out.println("hello");` line or beyond it.

Comment: maybe because: scan.hasNext() :)

Comment: I guess `if(i >= arr.length) break;`. insert this as the _first_ statement within the `while` loop.

Comment: After you input 1,2,3,4,5 enter - you will see `sud` 5 times after that press Ctr+Z if you are on windows else probably Ctrl+D on Linux.

Comment: array input is unknown

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading the data from `System.in`, `hasNext()` waits for you to enter more data when you are running in console mode.

In order to tell `Scanner` that there's no more input, you need to close the input stream. On Windows, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On UNIX, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Your code will also work if you put the input in a file, and redirect your program to read from a file.

**Note:** You need to protect your code from a user entering too much data. Add `i < arr.length` to the loop condition, otherwise your code will stop with an exception when end-users enter 11-th number.

```
while(i < arr.length && scan.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked .Can you tell me how to take unknown number of input without this problem.

Comment: @SudSwastik If you do not want to limit the number of items upfront, use a container that can grow when you add items to it, such as `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()`. You can call `list.add(scan.nextInt())` on it in a loop, then end the input with Ctrl+Z/Ctrl+D, and the list will contain all the items the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add an if statement to check for a specific input to stop taking input(break the loop)

```
 while(scan.hasNext()){
     String tmp = scan.next();
     if (tmp.equals("exit"))     
         break;
     else {
     arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
     System.out.println("sud");
     }
 }
 System.out.println("hello");
```

INPUT:

```
1 2 3 exit
```

OUTPUT:

```
sud
sud
sud
hello
```

Comment: this could throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw that is because the array is already initialized with size 10 assuming input wont be more than 10.